# Schengen visa from Ireland to go Zurich for few days as a Bangladeshi

Tags: schengen-visas, italy, switzerland

As a Bangladeshi passport holder in Ireland, I contacted the swiss embassy here in Dublin; they say I need to go to their embassy in London to apply for a visa, which is a bit weird for me because I need a visa to go to the even UK. If I apply for a Schengen visa to the Italian/German embassy here and visit Italy/Germany for a few days from Dublin, then with that same visa, can I travel to Zurich for a few days?

Answer (score 5):

If you make your other visit(s) longer or more important than your visit to Switzerland, yes you can combine several Schengen countries into one trip and get the visa from an Ireland based embassy.

But remember that embassies do not like visa shopping (getting a visa from an other embassy than the one you actually should go to.)

If you go this route your other stay really has to be the longer one, as more important is hard to prove.

Comment: OR if they make their Schengen port of entry one in Italy/Germany

Comment: @Ozzy the port of entry is not a factor in determining where the application should be filed unless there is no main destination.

Answer (score 3):

Can I advise that before you do anything further you contact the **Swiss Embassy in London** and ask directly if there is a specific process you can follow as a resident in Ireland?  Do not contact TLS first as they are hopeless with these requests (for anything that is not straight forwards you won't be able to trust the answer they give you, even if they seem confident).  It is possible that there will be a specific process to follow as a non UK resident.  You would normally need to leave your passport for the processing which would also prevent you from leaving the UK so this leads me to think they may have a solution.

I speak from personal experience that the Embassy has a different process for the application of long term D visas for Irish residents than the websites or TLS are aware of and so I suspect they may also have similar for Schengen visas.  It may not completely stop you from attending for biometrics but you may find that you only need to travel the once, or perhaps even by post the application if your biometrics are  stored already from previous applications.

This is definitely the next step you should be taking as they may surprise you.  The embassy is very busy, and may take a while to reply to emails, but you can call them.

Answer (score 0):

Inform the Italian/German consulate, where you make the application, that you cannot make the application at the swiss consulate (your main destination), because they only offer such applications in an area (without an offer to a local alternative consulate) for applicants that require an extra, **expensive** visa, solely to apply for a Schengen Visa.

Your your travel plan should show that the consulate where you apply would be considered a 'second' best main destination.

As unfortunate as it is that 3rd country nationals, who are residents of the **Common Travel Area** (CTA), may not travel freely within this area may be - this should not lead into (effectualy) preventing an applicant to apply for an Schengen Visa without incuring undue costs (for a standard visa presently £100).

Comment: Do you have evidence that this strategy will actually work, rather than "should" work according to your beliefs?

Comment: @ajd Article 8(3) Visa Code (REGULATION (EC) No 810/2009). Any further questions?

Comment: The Swiss government [is quite clear](https://www.eda.admin.ch/countries/ireland/en/home/visa/entry-ch/up-90-days/where-to-apply-schengen.html) that Irish residents of most nationalities which require a visa are expected to apply at the Austrian Embassy in Dublin, but Bangladeshi (and some other) nationals are expected to apply at the Swiss Embassy in London, or at the TLScontact counter in London, Manchester, or Edinburgh. Ignoring this rule based on your view that you know the Schengen requirements better than the embassies is likely to result in denied applications.

Comment: @ajd That doesn't change the fact that Article 8(3) Visa Code still applies. And kindly read read the visa code propery and you will find that another Embassy will only refuse to accept the application.

Comment: @ajd Wierd is also: *Copy of **UK** current account bank statements for the last three months*. and *Original (hand signed) employment letter from **the employer in the UK** confirming the purpose and duration of the trip to Switzerland* How should someone living in the Republic of Ireland fulfill such requirements?

Comment: You have once again completely misunderstood Schengen regulations. What does article 8(3) have to do with the question asked by @ajd? Article 8(5) is somewhat relevant but it is still entirely up to the member states. As a whole, article 8 does not create an enforceable right for applicants to ignore a requirement to apply in another country, no matter how onerous that requirement might be.

Comment: And if Switzerland had such an arrangement, it could be with any other Schengen country that's represented in Ireland. These visa representation arrangements then apply to all applicants in the area, who would have to apply to the member state chosen by Switzerland. There would be no reason to apply to either Italy or Germany.

Comment: One may wonder if it might be deliberate for Switzerland to effectively ask the UK to "pre-screen" visa applications for nationals of these countries...